# STL container classes in UEFI compiled code

Tags: c++, c, stl, uefi

Recently while learning about UEFI (proposed replacement for BIOS), I tried coding some stuff and compile using EDK2. The ides was to generate .EFI binary which I can launch on entering UEFI shell. I was able to do so. Perfectly!

Now my code involves pure C style (basically missing C++ facilities, e.g. classes, constructors, virtuals and STL container classes). I was wondering if I can use STL container classes (like strings, vectors, hash-maps) and still be able to compile and run my .EFI for UEFI?

I researched a bit and found a lot of discouragement! Basically, what I gathered was:

1. UEFI is tied closely to C. The open-source implementations don’t support C++
2. new and delete not supported.
3. vtable generation is compiler dependent, so generated code is not portable

Beside, there was a lot to learn from this site:
[UEFI Programming](http://uefi.blogspot.in/2012/08/uefi-application-programming-system.html)

But unfortunately I was left confused!

My question is that can I use STL classes (std::string/std::vector/std::map)in my code and compile it using EDK2 for UEFI environment?

I would appreciate if somebody can point me to a solution/direction to look for. Right now, the only option I'm working with is one C-Implementation for containers found here:
[UTHash implementation](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/index.html)

Is there a way around?

Comment: I know nothing about UEFI programming, but if you can not use dynamic memory allocation (well, probably, there is no such memory dedicated to UEFI in hardware), I think there is no good way of implementation of C++ containers. I could be wrong though ;) BTW, it's not a proposal, but already being used for several years. For example, my motherboard has UEFI.

Comment: If you don't understand what's involved in porting/using the C++ runtime on an embedded platform, then effectively no, you cannot use STL classes.

Comment: My bad! Wrong choice of words! Indeed it's already being used for several years! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the memory or vtable. UEFI has efficient dynamic memory allocation. And new and delete can be implemented. As well as vtable, internally it's just a regular C structure! The problem though is that STL **trows exceptions**. And exceptions are platform/OS dependent. In windows STL exceptions underneath use SEH (Structured Exception Handling) which is OS dependent and it's closely bound to thread internals. In UEFI there is no such mechanism but it can be implemented though. Even though it is a very non trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

Point 2 shouldn't be a major problem. The reliance on `new` and `delete` is primarily through `std::allocator`, a default argument to each container template. But that's only a default. Provide your own allocator (using whatever memory allocation is available on UEFI) and you have a good chance of getting it to work.

It's unlikely your STL implementation uses vtables anyway, so 3 isn't a big deal either. However, `<iostream>` will be another matter.